# Android Things: How to exit Android Settings screen?

Tags: android-activity, android-things, activity-finish

I succeed to show *Android Date Settings* by calling :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

but I don't know how to exit, there is no cancel/update button, no back button or navigation bar.

Would anyone know how to leave this screen?

I use *Android Things 0.5.1-devpreview* on *RPi3* with this [example code](https://gist.github.com/aberteau/c41d8b42056b97cda4958c6e97d6401c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to close *Android*'s settings app you can either send a back button press event

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

or force close the settings app

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.settings
```

Or send an input event **programmatically**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 4");
```

*Just keep in mind that your app goes to background when the Android settings app gets started "hiding" your app's UI. You'll need to figure out how to trigger the programmatic solution*.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that there is no CR. (Enter key submit my comment). Thank you very much for your proposals. I tested the first 2 and they worked. The main inconvenience, in my case, is that I would like to be able to leave this screen directly from the device which runs the application. I realize an alarm clock based on an RPi3, since it will not always have Wifi to synchronize the time, I wanted to be able to set it directly from the LCD screen. But without button back or the navigation bar, the solution is perhaps to add a button on the GPIO that will call the code in 3rd solution

Answer (score 1):

In your code just start some activity and it will overtake the settings screen.

For example, if u open settings screen to enable Location, u set a broadcast listener to On Location status change. The moment user enables location, you'll receive broadcast and there u start your activity. The settings screen will automatically close.