# Android things back from settings or other activities

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I used Android Things on Raspberry PI 3 with touch screen. And i need configure wifi connection, for example. Call WiFi settings via intent, after configure i need return to my application, but i have only one button, which connect to pin. This button must be work as Back button on android device. 
When button press executed this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 4");
```

But i get exception:

```
java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
```

When i send command via command line from PC - all work good, but on device - Permission denied
What wrong? This is because my android not rooted?

Also tried call OnBackPress in main activity, but this work only in my application and not back from settings.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Also explain where you run the code? Are you running it on an Android device or on a desktop machine?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  Evgeniy is running his code on Raspberry PI 3. I don't think any verifiable code is necessary to reproduce the issue.  There is just no back button on AndroidThings.  I have the same problem.  There must be some way to click the back button, but I can't find any.

Comment: [Android Things: How to exit Android Settings screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139931/3290339)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root, you will not be able to execute direct key presses on your device with a shell command. You would need to use an [InputDriver](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/input.html) to have your button send an event to the system (though I'm unsure if it would support the BACK button).

Additionally, if you are running a shell command on the device, you don't need `adb shell`. You're already in the shell.

Comment: `Android Things` is root.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of AndroidThings (DP6) you can setup the Wifi Connection through the launcher (before you install your app).

[image: wifi launcher]

> This launcher is visible when no other developer-provided IOT_LAUNCHER Activity is present.

Once you have setup the wifi (using your touchscreen) you can then install your app.

---

If you wanted a more programmatic approach, you could install your app but disable the activity that has IOT_LAUNCHER intent. This will let the Launcher show. Meanwhile you have registered to monitor for connectivity changes, when the wifi is connected you re-enable your launcher activity. (This is just theoretical I haven't tried this).

---

With the latest version DP8 , you now need:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

In your intent, which replaces IOT_LAUNCHER (https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html)

Comment: he asked how to configure wifi from his screen then go back to his app.

Comment: My understanding is that he needs "back from settings or other activities".  And WiFi configuration was just an example.